# Why we put 10Kohm resistor in parallel with 144Kohm that exist inside USB-6008?

Tags: sensor, temperature

When using the LM35 Temperature Sensor and USB-6008, a 10K resistor is placed between GND and AI0 which connect on the LM35 to GND and Vout, respectively.

[image]

Referring to the Analog Input circuitry in the USB-6008 datasheet,
you'll find the equivalent internal resistance is 144K between GND and AIO, and AIO is at 1.4V with no signal. (They use two in parallel and one in series, and the combination is 144 Kohm: (30.9*39.2/30.9+39.2)+127=144.27 Kohm)

Why do we need a 10K resistor in parallel with the 144K inside the USB-6008?

[Datasheet for LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf)
[Datasheet for USB-6008](http://home.hit.no/~finnh/videos/topics/labview_analog_io/371303.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps you should link supporting datasheets/documentation. Also, as it's drawn, I don't see how the two resistors are parallel..

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Thanks for at least posting some sort of a drawing. Please provide a link to datasheet for any devices you reference. If you read the datasheet you may find the answer to your question. There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar if you wish to add a better schematic.

Comment: 144Kohm resistor exist inside the DAQ is connected with GND and any analog input potrs, in our case AI0.

Comment: Datasheet for UDB-6008: http://goo.gl/jGkK8S

Answer (score 2):

The LM35 has very low current sinking capability (1uA). The USB-6008 AIO pins are internally terminated to 1.4V with 144K. If you don't add something to sink the current from the AIO termination, the LM35 output would just sit near 1.4V (no lower than 1.4V - 144K * 1uA) and does nothing.